# I need an idea how to write the dataframe horizontally, and no repeat the 'ProblemCode' column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

currently:

| ProblemGroup | month | Count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 362 |
| A | 2 | 485 |
| B | 1 | 400 |
| B | 2 | 487 |

I need it this way:

| month | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 362 | 400 |
| 2 | 485 | 487 |

Comment: Please take the [tour] and read [ask]; this is neither a code-writing nor tutorial service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `pivot_table` for that

```
import pandas as pd

data = [["A", 1, 362], ["A", 2, 485], ["B", 1, 400], ["B", 2, 487]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=["ProblemGroup", "Month", "Count"])
pd.pivot_table(df, values="Count", index="Month", columns="ProblemGroup")
```

outputs:

```
ProblemGroup    A    B
Month                 
1             362  400
2             485  487
```